# Как переместить элемент из одного unordered_map в другой зная только <key>

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Есть два контейнера unordered_map:

```
     unordered_map <int, vector <Result>> mapTmp;
     unordered_map <int, vector <Result>> mapResult;
```

например в mapTmp есть массив элементов который лежит под индексом `[25]`, как переместить элемент `mapTmp[25]` в `mapResult[25]` зная только индекс?

Comment: Из вопроса неясно, имеется ли уже элемент с ключом 25 в контейнере mapResult.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вроде в map как только используем оператор [] элемент создается, даже если его не было

Comment: Вы не ответили на мой вопрос.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow в конкретно этом случае контейнер mapResult пустой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно сработать такое:

```
mapResult[25] = std::move(mapTmp[25]);
mapTmp.erase(25);
```

После первой строки `mapTmp[25]` валиден, но [находится в неопределённом состоянии](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028318/276994).

---

Для более сложных случаев составного ключа хотелось бы, конечно, переместить и *ключ*. Это, кажется, [невозможно без копирования](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115869/276994).

Comment: а вот так возможно: `mapResult[25].swap(mapTmp[25])`?

Comment: @xttz: По идее. можно, но всё равно нужно будет `mapTmp.erase(25);` (иначе в `mapTmp` останется пустой массив).